# How do I load a datagridview from a database based on the child node selected from a treeview?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, treeview

How do I load a datagridview from a database based on the child node selected from a treeview? Ex. If manufacturer name is selected (manufacturer name is the child node), load all products for that manufacturer

```
String strConn = "Server = .\\SQLEXPRESS;Database = Northwind;Integrated 
Security = SSPI;";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Suppliers", conn);
SqlDataAdapter daCategories = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from 
Categories", conn);

da.Fill(ds, "Suppliers");
daCategories.Fill(ds, "Categories");

ds.Relations.Add("Cat_Supply", 
ds.Tables["Categories"].Columns["CategoryID"], 
ds.Tables["Suppliers"].Columns["CategoryID"]);

foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables["Categories"].Rows)
{
   TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(dr["CategoryName"].ToString());
   foreach (DataRow drChild in dr.GetChildRows("Cat_Supply"))
   {
          tn.Nodes.Add(drChild["CompanyNamde"].ToString());
   }
   treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a spearate sub to load the `DataGridView`, with a parameter of ehither the category name as you have it, or CategoryID (better, you can store it as a tag in `TreeVeiwItem`, I believe).

C#:

```
private void LoadCategoryTest(Int32 CategoryID)
{
    string cmdText = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, CompanyName, Details, PurchasingCode FROM Products WHERE CategoryID = " + CategoryID + "; ";
    DataSet ds;
    DataTable dt;
    ds = DatabaseAccess.GetQueryResults(cmdText);
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        dt = ds.Tables(0);
        this.dgBends.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Private Sub LoadCategoryTest(CategoryID As Int32)
    Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, CompanyName, Details, PurchasingCode FROM Products WHERE CategoryID = " & CategoryID & "; "
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim dt As DataTable
    ds = DatabaseAccess.GetQueryResults(cmdText)
    If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        dt = ds.Tables(0)
        Me.dgBends.DataSource = dt
    End If
End Sub
```

Obviously, put whatever you want to get into the SQL query.
Note: I don't explain the database function used, I believe that's out of the scope of this question. To use the it, use just treeview event like `NodeMouseClick` (or `AfterSelect`, etc., depending on what you aim to achieve):

C#

```
private void TreeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode n = (TreeNode)sender;
    LoadDetail(n.Tag);  // provided, you saved CategoryID into treenode tag
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeMouseClick(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseClick
    Dim n As TreeNode = CType(sender, TreeNode)
    Call LoadDetail(n.Tag)  ' provided, you saved CategoryID into treenode tag
End Sub
```

You can do the same with CategoryName string.

Note: This basic example does not includes things like parametric queries or binding. It is functional, though.